# Populate ClaimsPrincpal with access token claims/attributes using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect

Tags: openid-connect, asp.net-core-6.0, claims

I have setup a simple ASP.NET Core 6 website where I'm using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect` for connecting to a keycloak provider using auth code flow.

It all works fine.. but..

I have noticed that the final `ClaimsPrincipal` only gets populated with claims from the `id_token`, and none from the provided `access_token`. This basically forces me to send the custom claims / attributes both in the `access_token` and in the `id_token`.

Is there anyway to also append the claims from the `access_token`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client (AddOpenIDConnect) should not need to care about what is found inside the access token. So, yes, the easiest is to add the claims (in both tokens). But usually you need different claims in each one, as the ones in the access tokens is only needed for authorization.

However, there is one further option and that is to hook into the events inside AddOpenIDConnect and create a new ClaimsPrincipal object based on the two tokens. see https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/1525

the third option is to look into something called Claims transformations.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/claims?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: That the client should not care about the access token for population the principal.. is that a general rule for OpenId Connect, or a specific rule for the Microsoft implementation of OIDC? Asking since the guy helping me configure ADFS with a new client told me that in general the access token should be used for custom claims.. which I kind of doubt due to MS implementation.. (but then again, Im not sure if thats just the decision MS have made, or if its a general rule)

Comment: Its more a general rule I think, the ID-token is used by the client to create the session cookie. The client uses the access key to access the APIs and the client does not care about what it contains. You can also get the user claims from the userinfo endpoint, and not from the tokens, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectoptions.getclaimsfromuserinfoendpoint?view=aspnetcore-7.0